# Back in Time says "working..." but nothing happens

Tags: backup, backintime

When I try to create a backup of my mint17 machine, Back in Time says "working..." but it then it stuck. After more than 24h the status hasn't changed and no backup is made / available.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

> pepperonas@pepperonas-Allstar ~ $ backintime --debug backup WARNING:
>   import keyring failed
>
> Back In Time Version: 1.0.34
>
> Back In Time comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
>   and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions; type
>   `backintime --license' for details.
>
> Ignore option: --debug

Comment: Questions on Mint should be asked on [unix.se].

Comment: Ohh, I'm sorry :-/ I didn't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please remove the old lock and message files

```
rm -f ~/.local/share/backintime/worker*
```

and try again.

If it still doesn't work please install current version from our PPA `bit-team/stable`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bit-team/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Open a Terminal, run `backintime --debug backup` and add the output to your question.

<sub>I'm member of BIT Dev-Team</sub>

Comment: Thanks Germar, it's nice that a dev is answering to my question. :) Unfortunately the issue still exists. I will reinstall backintime and try it again. Is it possible that the backup is too large? I'm attempting to create a ~50GB backup and store it on a other hard drive (which has ~500GB free). When I try to delete a backup backintime's gui get's frozen (I don't have any experience as a linux dev - but in java I would say it's because of the thread)

Comment: I guess it was because the target drive (to store the backup) was formatted as ntfs..? I wasn't able to delete files from this drive, as well. Now it's ext4 formatted, maybe it will work better :) I will update my question soon.

Comment: @MartinPfeffer the command I provided should be run AFTER upgrading ;) The old version can't handle that arguments. The size doesn't matter but using a native Linux filesystem is always better!